# Cronjob every 3 hours and cronjob every 3+1 hours

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have two sets of cronjob I want to run. First one should run every 3 hours and the second one should run also at every 3 hours but one hour later than the first set. What is the correct syntax?

```
// every 3 hours
17 */3  * * *   root  script
// every 3h +1 ?
17 */3+1    * * *   root  script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
17 */3    * * *  every-3-hours-starting-at-0-script
17 1-23/3 * * *  every-3-hours-starting-at-1-script
```

The hour field on the first line could have been written as `0-23/3`.  A `*` in that field is just a convenient abbreviation for `0-23`.

The pattern continues as you would expect.  Every 3 hours starting at 2 would be:

```
17 2-23/3 * * *  every-3-hours-starting-at-2-script
```